# How to set permissions on a file (key) in AWS S3 using Python Boto Library?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm experiencing a problem with permissions on a file in AWS S3 after updating it with a Python script using the Boto library.

Here is the command that I'm using to update the file in S3:

```
k.set_contents_from_string(json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4))
```

The file gets updated correctly, however the permissions get changed which is very strange to me.

Before updating the file, the permissions are:

*Granteed: awsprod  Open/Download(checked)   View Permissions(checked)   Edit Permissions(checked)*

After updating the file, the permissions are gone and nothing shows under permissions when looking it through the AWS Dashboard/Console.

After the permissions are removed, downloading the file is no longer possible and it fails every time.

Via aws cli:

```
A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

Via aws console:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>A6E4AA2E3A3B9429</RequestId>
<HostId>
47gMhTpdFRAYm1cP4noivQlNEeB/cxHr2QFRXewNERdYcGcan2QU/fOVQ/upOl7Zp9fNIXLUnkk=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

My access is via IAM, and my user has the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy giving me full access to S3.

What is even more intriguing is that I have 2 AWS accounts, and the same script works well in one of them without changing the file permissions, and on the other account I have the problem described above. Now, you might think that I might have different policy access to S3 between these 2 aws accounts. I already checked that, and both accounts have the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy.

So, even if this is a problem on the AWS account setup, I would like to add to my script a line to set the file permissions back to the way it was before updating it. I think that should do the trick and allow me to download the file after running the Python script.

How can I set file permissions (not bucket) in S3 using Boto?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [policy](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_string), with one of the [canned acl strings](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html#setting-getting-the-access-control-list-for-buckets-and-keys), something like:

```
k.set_contents_from_string(json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4), policy=<ACL STRING>)
```

Comment: I resolved this issue by creating /etc/boto.cfg file with the aws credentials. I was not aware that BOTO doesn't look the credentials in .aws/credentials file.